# How can I create a new xml node in an existing xml document?

Tags: c#, xml

I have xml file where I save my settings for my application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings>
  <Version>Growthanalyzer v1.0.1</Version>
  <Update>Automatic</Update>
  <Databases>
    <Database>
      <Name>RoomOne</Name>
      <StartMeasureTime>10/5/2015 12:00:00 AM</StartMeasureTime>
      <EndMeasureTime>11/12/2015 12:00:00 AM</EndMeasureTime>
      <FirstMeasureTime>10/27/2015 12:00:00 AM</FirstMeasureTime>
      <LastMeasureTime>11/24/2015 12:12:13 PM</LastMeasureTime>    
    </Database>
  </Databases>
  <Archives>
    <Archive>
      <Name>RoomOne</Name>
      <FirstMeasureTime>10/27/2015 12:00:00 AM</FirstMeasureTime>
      <LastMeasureTime>11/24/2015 12:12:13 PM</LastMeasureTime>
    </Archive>
  </Archives>
</Settings>
```

To start with I will have have one database and one archive, but in the future it is possible to have more databases and archives. I would like to save information for these things in an XML file. How can add another Database node and Archive node like this template, dynamically when user clicks some button.

**EDIT:**

here is what I try now but still is not working:

```
public static void CreateDatabaseNode(string newXmlNode, string xmlParrent, string value)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"D:/VS_Projects/helper/v1.0.1/Growthanalyzer.App/Resources/Settings.xml");
        //doc.Load(@"../../Resources/Settings.xml");
        XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/Settings/" + xmlParrent);

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            if (node.Name == xmlParrent)
            {
                XmlNode newNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Database", xmlParrent);
                node.AppendChild(newNode);
                break;
            }
        }
        doc.Save(@"D:/VS_Projects/helper/v1.0.1/Growthanalyzer.App/Resources/Settings.xml");
    }
```

**EDIT:** Now is created this type `<Database xmlns="Databases" />`.
How can remove `xmlns="Databases"` from Database node.

Comment: Comments like "but still is not working" are not very helpful. What error do you get? What happens at the moment and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question, and don't add [Solved] to the title. :)

Comment: OK sorry @CodeCaster just I finally solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [XmlDocument.CreateNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162365(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation,
dont pass `xmlParrent` string in `CreateNode`, just pass `""`:

```
XmlNode newNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Database", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem thanks to @Christian Holm Jørgensen and I post the method who now in my case is working perfect:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Create new node by design
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newXmlNode">New xml parrent node</param>
    /// <param name="xmlParrent">Where is add newXmlNode</param>
    /// <param name="childNodes">all child nodes with their values</param>
    public static void CreateDatabaseNode(string newXmlNode, string xmlParrent, Dictionary<string, string> childNodes)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"D:/VS_Projects/helper/v1.0.1/Growthanalyzer.App/Resources/Settings.xml");
        //doc.Load(@"../../Resources/Settings.xml");
        XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/Settings/" + xmlParrent);

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            if (node.Name == xmlParrent)
            {
                XmlNode newNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Database", "");
                node.AppendChild(newNode);

                foreach (var child in childNodes)
                {
                    XmlNode childNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, child.Key, "");
                    childNode.InnerText = child.Value;
                    newNode.AppendChild(childNode);
                }

                break;
            }
        }
        doc.Save(@"D:/VS_Projects/helper/v1.0.1/Growthanalyzer.App/Resources/Settings.xml");
    }
```

I'll be glad if is help in someone else with the same "problem".